# Относительный размер окна

Tags: python, tkinter

Пишу программку на Python, только начал изучать python.
Как сделать так чтобы ОКНО было относительного размера монитора.

---

Пример:
Если у меня монитор 1440х990, а у пользователя 1920х1080 и другие...

```
from tkinter import * 

root = Tk()

root.title('Окно') 
root.geometry('1000x680') 
root.resizable(width=False, height=False) 
root.configure(background='#000000') 

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Покажите пожалуйста пример кода с отображением окна.

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте так

```
from tkinter import * 

root = Tk()

root.title('Окно') 

w = root.winfo_screenwidth()    # ширина экрана
h = root.winfo_screenheight()   # высота экрана
print(f'w = {w}, h = {h}')

#root.geometry('1000x680') 
root.geometry(f'{w}x{h}')

root.resizable(width=False, height=False) 
root.configure(background='#000000') 

root.mainloop()
```

---

**Update**

а так

```
root = Tk()

root.title('Окно') 

w = root.winfo_screenwidth()    # ширина экрана
h = root.winfo_screenheight()   # высота экрана
print(f'w = {w}, h = {h}')

w = w//2                        # середина экрана
h = h//2 
print(f'w = {w}, h = {h}')

w = w - 500                     # смещение от середины
h = h - 340
print(f'w = {w}, h = {h}')

#root.geometry('1000x680') 
root.geometry('1000x680+{}+{}'.format(w, h))

root.resizable(width=False, height=False) 
root.configure(background='#000000') 

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: не какая-то белеберда получается

Comment: @Andryxa  что такое  `белеберда` ?

Comment: Ну вообщем, не то что нужно

Comment: @Andryxa а что нужно ?

Comment: нужно чтобы окно открывалось, индивидуально к каждому монитору пользователя.

Comment: @Andryxa попробуйте обновление

Comment: сойдет, я поиграю с размерами

Answer (score 0):

Вот так точно должно работать!

```
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()

root.title('Окно') 

w = root.winfo_screenwidth()    # ширина экрана
h = root.winfo_screenheight()   # высота экрана
print(f'w = {w}, h = {h}')

rw = w - 200
rh = w - 100

w = w//2  - rw//2                  # середина экрана
h = h//2  - rh//2

root.geometry('{}x{}+{}+{}'.format(rw, rh,w, h))

root.resizable(width=False, height=False) 

root['bg'] = 'black'

root.mainloop()
```